# Difference between ToString and IntoString

Tags: rust, rust-obsolete

I'm wondering what the difference is between:

```
"some string".to_string()
```

And

```
"some string".into_string()
```

The former seems to come from [ToString](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/to_string/trait.ToString.html), which is quite clear.

However, the latter seems to comes from [IntoString](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/to_string/trait.IntoStr.html), which is less clear to me.

What does it mean to `consume` a value ? What is the difference between the two traits ?

---

Additional information after doing some digging around.

Here's [the current implementation of `into_string`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/ec1d34eb276f8eedf026143d18c9416dc5836d50/src/libcollections/string.rs#L771) for a `String`. As you can see, it only returns itself, so no allocation is done.

Comment: Looks like one converting to original value but other one is not converting to self returning a one more string so that original will be remain same.Not sure you must have to test,

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Move Semantics

> What does it mean to `consume` a value?

Consuming a value has to do with moving a value. Before I discuss the differences between the two traits, I'll give some examples of what it means to move a value. Let's create a [`Vec`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) of [`Ascii`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ascii/struct.Ascii.html) characters: `asciis`.

```
fn main() {
    let asciis = vec!['h'.to_ascii(), 'i'.to_ascii()];
    println!("{}", asciis);
}
```

[Internally](http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/collections/home/rustbuild/src/rust-buildbot/slave/nightly-linux/build/src/libcollections/vec.rs.html#104-108), the `Vec` is a struct with three fields:

1. The length of the `Vec`.
2. The capacity of the `Vec`.
3. A pointer to the data managed by the `Vec`.

Pictorially, the memory layout of the `Vec` and the data it is managing may look something like this.

```
Stack: asciis           Heap: 
     +----------+            +----------+
0xF0 | data     | ----> 0xA0 | 'h'      |
     +----------+            +----------+
0xF4 | length   |       0xA1 | 'i'      |
     +----------+            +----------+
0xF8 | capacity |
     +----------+
```

When our `Vec` goes out of scope, it frees the memory it's managing. The freed memory is garbage to us. It would be erroneous to access freed memory. This would look something like the following. The `Vec` is gone and the memory on the heap has been freed.

```
                        Heap: 
                             +----------+
                        0xA0 | GARBAGE  |
                             +----------+
                        0xA1 | GARBAGE  |
                             +----------+
```

Now, let's go back to our code and try to make a copy of `asciis`.

```
fn main() {
    let asciis = vec!['h'.to_ascii(), 'i'.to_ascii()];
    {
        let an_attempted_copy = asciis; 
    }
    println!("{}", asciis);
}
```

Let's guess that `an_attempted_copy` is a copy of `asciis`. After we make the copy, our memory may look something like the following.

```
Stack: asciis           Heap:                   Stack: an_attempted_copy
     +----------+            +----------+            +----------+
0xF0 | data     | ----> 0xA0 | 'h'      | <---- 0xE0 | data     |
     +----------+            +----------+            +----------+
0xF4 | length   |       0xA1 | 'i'      |            | length   |
     +----------+            +----------+            +----------+
0xF8 | capacity |                                    | capacity |
     +----------+                                    +----------+
```

Right before we try to `println!` `asciis`, `an_attempted_copy` goes out of scope! Just like before, the data pointed to by our `Vec` is freed.

```
Stack: asciis           Heap:                   
     +----------+            +----------+            
0xF0 | data     | ----> 0xA0 | GARBAGE  | 
     +----------+            +----------+           
0xF4 | length   |       0xA1 | GARBAGE  |           
     +----------+            +----------+           
0xF8 | capacity |                                    
     +----------+
```

Uh oh, `asciis` is pointing into freed memory! This is bad news since we're just about to `println!` `asciis`.

So how would we remedy the situation? Well, here's two options.

1. When we copy `asciis` into `an_attempted_copy`, we could copy the data pointed to by `asciis` into a freshly allocated piece of memory. Other languages like C++ do this.
2. Instead of copying `asciis`, we can move it! This is what rust does.

So what does it mean to move? It means that `an_attempted_copy` will take ownership of the data previously pointed to by `asciis`. `asciis` loses ownership and we can't use it anymore. Let's rename `an_attempted_copy` for clarity.

```
fn main() {
    let asciis = vec!['h'.to_ascii(), 'i'.to_ascii()];
    {
        let actually_a_move = asciis; 
    }
    println!("{}", asciis);
}
```

Now, let's draw our memory layout right after we move into `actually_a_move`.

```
Stack: asciis           Heap:                   Stack: actually_a_move
     +----------+            +----------+            +----------+
0xF0 | GARBAGE  |       0xA0 | 'h'      | <---- 0xE0 | data     |
     +----------+            +----------+            +----------+
0xF4 | GARBAGE  |       0xA1 | 'i'      |            | length   |
     +----------+            +----------+            +----------+
0xF8 | GARBAGE  |                                    | capacity |
     +----------+                                    +----------+
```

`asciis` doesn't own the memory anymore, so we can't use `asciis` anymore. This means it's pretty much garbage. So if we can't use `asciis` anymore, what happens when we `println!` it? We get the following error.

```
<anon>:6:24: 6:30 error: use of moved value: `asciis`
<anon>:6         println!("{}", asciis);
                                ^~~~~~
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:23: 2:77 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 3:2 note: in expansion of println!
<anon>:6:9: 6:32 note: expansion site
<anon>:4:17: 4:32 note: `asciis` moved here because it has type `collections::vec::Vec<std::ascii::Ascii>`, which is moved by default (use `ref` to override)
<anon>:4             let actually_a_move = asciis;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

As expected, the rust compiler is telling us we were trying to use `ascii`, but `ascii` was a moved value; this is erroneous.

Move semantics (and related topics like borrowing and lifetimes) is tough stuff. I've only barely scratched the surface here. For more information, [rust by example](http://rustbyexample.com/move.html) and [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics) question are both good resources.

## `to_string` vs `into_string`

> What is the difference between the two traits?

Now that I've explored the concept of consuming or moving a value, let's get to the differences between the two traits. Let's first look at the type signature of `to_string`.

```
fn to_string(&self) -> String;
```

This function takes a reference to `self` and returns a fresh `String` for us to use. I haven't discussed references and how they affect movement, but trust me when I say no moving is done here.

Now let's look at the type signature of `into_string`.

```
fn into_string(self) -> String;
```

This function does not take a reference to `self`. Instead, `self` is  moved into the function.

So what are the implications of this difference? Let's take a look at an example.

```
fn main() {
    let asciis = vec!['h'.to_ascii(), 'i'.to_ascii()];
    let no_moves_here = asciis.to_string();
    println!("{}", asciis);
}
```

We again create a `Vec` of `Ascii` characters. Then, when we call `asciis.to_string()`, a brand new `String` is created and `asciis` is never moved. This code will build and run as you expect, printing out `[h, i]`. Now, let's use `into_string`.

```
fn main() {
    let asciis = vec!['h'.to_ascii(), 'i'.to_ascii()];
    let uh_oh_we_just_moved_asciis = asciis.into_string();
    println!("{}", asciis);
}
```

Here's the error message we get when trying to build this code.

```
<anon>:4:24: 4:30 error: use of moved value: `asciis`
<anon>:4         println!("{}", asciis);
                                ^~~~~~
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:23: 2:77 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 3:2 note: in expansion of println!
<anon>:4:9: 4:32 note: expansion site
<anon>:3:42: 3:48 note: `asciis` moved here because it has type `collections::vec::Vec<std::ascii::Ascii>`, which is non-copyable (perhaps you meant to use clone()?)
<anon>:3         let uh_oh_we_just_moved_asciis = asciis.into_string();
                                                  ^~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

So what happened? Well `asciis` is being moved into the function `into_string`. Just like the last time we tried to use `asciis` after we moved it, the rust compiler will reject our code.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I still have a doubt about the last part. Does this mean that `to_string`, since it only borrows temporarily, must make a copy in memory in order to return a String and that `into_string` since it consumes our string can return a different type pointing to the same bytes in memory?

Answer (score 3):

This is a reference to "move semantics," which admittedly has basically no documentation. Sorry about that! The difference is that if a value moves, you can't use it anymore. In other words, this works:

```
fn main() {
    let x = "hello".to_string();

    let y = x.to_string();
    let z = x.into_string();
}
```

but this errors:

```
fn main() {
    let x = "hello".to_string();

    let z = x.into_string();
    let y = x.to_string();
}
```

with

```
<anon>:5:13: 5:14 error: use of moved value: `x`
<anon>:5     let y = x.to_string();
                     ^
<anon>:3:17: 3:18 note: `x` moved here because it has type `collections::string::String`, which is non-copyable (perhaps you meant to use clone()?)
<anon>:3         let z = x.into_string();
                         ^
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: That does make sense. Does it mean `into_string()` is meant to be faster? Otherwise, what would the reason to use `into_string()` over `to_string()`?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but yes, it would seem to me that it would be faster, since it only copies the pointer, and not the data.

Comment: The `into` pattern is intended to provide optimization oportunities, but in the example of converting a string slice to a `String`, `into_string` is no faster (the `String`s buffer can't be reused from anywhere so must be allocated fresh). Sadly, the only place `into_string` currently gets the optimization is the [implementation for `MaybeOwned`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcollections/str.rs#L610), a little-loved type. The obvious place to do the optimization is converting from UTF-8 `Vec<[u8]>`.